# AWS lightsail wordpress multisite static IP not Working

Tags: amazon-web-services, ip

When creating an AWS Lightsail instance with the WordPress Multisite preset, upon visiting the public ip it shows up as expected.

However, as soon as I attach a static IP to it and try to visit it in the browser, it keeps loading infinitely.

Why is that?

Comment: I have the same issue - ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT